# How do i increase the 100 limit when I fetch data from an endpoint using apollo?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

When I try to fetch data from a graphQL endpoint, it limits the amount of data returned to 100. How do I increase it?

client:

```
export const dexCandlesGraph = chainId => {
  const uri = DEXCANDLES_SUBGRAPH[chainId ?? ChainId.AVALANCHE]
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: createHttpLink({
      uri: uri
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })
}
```

query:

```
export const dexCandlesQuery = gql`
  query dexCandlesQuery($token0: String!, $token1: String!, $period: Int!) {
    candles(orderBy: time, orderDirection: asc, where: { token0: $token0, token1: $token1, period: $period }) {
      time
      open
      low
      high
      close
    }
  }
`
```

Making the query:

```
const results = await dexCandles.query({
  query: dexCandlesQuery,
  variables: { token0: sortedToken0, token1: sortedToken1, period }
})
// Number of maximum results returned is 100
```

Comment: Do you have access to the resolver code? if yes please share it

Comment: What's the resolver code?